# Redirecting IP to CNAME Using IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a website running on IP address *1.2.3.4* with hostname *www.host.com*. The web server only have one website running on it, and it can be accessed by *http://1.2.3.4*, *http://www.host.com*, *http://www.cname.com*. I prefer users to access it by a CNAME *www.cname.com* (which maps to *www.host.com*), so I want to redirect traffic coming from *http://1.2.3.4* or *http://www.host.com* to *http://www.cname.com*. Is it possible to achieve it with IIS URL Rewrite?

I tried the following rule but keeps getting redirect loop error.

```
<rule name="RedirectToMitigatr" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^((?!www.cname.com).)*$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cname.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

What I *think* the rule should do is that it matches anything doesn't contain *www.cname.com* to *https://www.cname.com*. But apparently it's not :p

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually redirect traffic from an IP address to another. 
I'm making the following assumptions:
1. you want your website on www.cname.com
2. host.com should redirect to www.cname.com

You are receiving an error since you are essentially redirecting traffic from www.cname.com to www.cname.com . You need to set url match to www.host.com

To do this,first you need to point www.cname.com to the same directory as your website host.com

Assuming you have mapped the name servers correctly, create a new virtual host for cname.com and point it to the SAME directory where you want your website

Visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576 for more information

```
<rule name="RedirectToMitigatr" stopProcessing="true">

<match url="^((?!www.host.com).)*$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cname.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Somesh, thank you first the answer, but perhaps I should explain more clearer. I only have one website running on the web server. The web server can be accessed by three ways, IP (1.2.3.4) and DN (www.host.com and www.cname.com). What I want is if the visitor type in 1.2.3.4 or www.host.com, he/she will be redirected to www.cname.com.

Comment: I can achieve redirecting traffic from http://www.cname.com to https://www.cname.com, but not http://www.host.com to http://www.cname.com.

Comment: why would u redirect from cname.com to cname.com? They are the same domain. Try the above route. It redirects from host.com to cname.com

Comment: StackOverflow hid the protocal. I meant I can redirect http:cname.com to https:cname.com, but not https:host.com to https:cname.com.

Comment: what did stack overflow do? It'd be easier if you mentioned the actual domains